# Proving the set of all finite graphs is countable

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How would we prove countability for the set of all finite graphs $G = (V,E)$, for $V ⊆ \mathbb{N}$? I know that $V$ and $E$ are finite. I also know here are no repeated edges. Also there can be multiple different, isomorphic graphs on $V$ vertices. I think I can prove it by proving the set is the same size of the set of natural numbers. Not sure how to do that though. Is it enough to say that since there can be multiple different graphs on $V$ vertices, the set of all finite graphs is countably infinite and therefore it has the same cardinality as the natural numbers.

Also, similarly is the set of all infinite graphs over a fixed, countably infinite set of vertices countable?

Answer (score 2):

The set of all finite graphs with vertex set $V \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ can be written as the union over all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of all graphs with vertex set $V \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$. Since the latter is finite (it's size is bounded above by $2^{n} \cdot 2^{n \choose 2}$), this shows that the former is a countable union of finite sets, so it is countable.

The set $\mathcal{G}$ of all (potentially infinite) graphs on $\mathbb{N}$ is not countable. For example, we can identify $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ via a bijection. Now for each subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we may define a graph $G_A$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ with edge set $E_A = \{\{(a,0),(a,1)\}: a \in A\}$. This gives an injection of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ into $\mathcal{G}$, so the latter has cardinality at least that of the continuum.

EDIT: It occurs to me that the latter example is a bit unsatisfactory in that, while it gives uncountably many graphs on a countably infinite vertex set, these graphs belong to countably many isomorphism classes (determined by the cardinality of $A$). It is not difficult to come up with another representation of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which avoids this issue. For example, given $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, let $G_A$ be a graph which is made up of disjoint cliques of size $a$ for each $a \in A$. Then for $A \neq B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ the graphs $G_A$ and $G_B$ will be non-isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each number $n\geq 0$, the number $k_n$ of graphs with $n$ vertices is finite.

So you get a complete list of all finite graphs in the order $n=0,1,2,\ldots$:

$0: G_{0,0}$ (empty graph)

...

$n:  G_{1,n},\ldots, G_{1,k_n}$

...

You can number the graphs in this list.

For this, you can provide a function $f:\Bbb N_0\rightarrow\Bbb N_0$ that computes for each $m$, the position $f(m)$ of the $m$th graph in this list. Its not hard to specify $f$ which depends on $k_0,k_1,\ldots$.

Comment: This doesn't match the definition in OP: isomorphic graphs with different vertex labels are counted as different, so there are infinitely many $1$-vertex graphs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- In a graph with $3$ vertices, there are $\binom{3}{2}=3$ possible edges. Each edge can either be present or not, so the total number of graphs with three vertices is $2^\binom{3}{2}=8$.
- In a graph with $4$ vertices, there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possible edges. Each edge can either be present or not, so the total number of graphs with four vertices is $2^\binom{4}{2}=32$.
- In a graph with $n$ vertices, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ possible edges. Each edge can either be present or not, so the total number of graphs with $n$ vertices is $2^\binom{n}{2}$.

So you can define a bijective correspondence between the natural numbers and the finite graphs in the following way:

- the one-vertex graph corresponds to $1$
- the two two-vertex graphs are assigned to $2$ and $3$
- the $2^\binom{n}{2}$ graphs with $n$ vertices are assigned numbers between $2+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} 2^\binom{i}{2}$ and $1+\sum_{i=2}^{n} 2^\binom{i}{2}$. Inside this set, the graphs can be ordered in any reasonable way. For example, the index of an $n$-vertex graph is
  $$2+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} 2^\binom{i}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{2}}b_k2^{k-1}$$

where $b_k$ is $0$ if the $k$-th possible edge of the graph is not present, and $b_k$ is $1$ if the $k$-th possible edge of the graph is present. The "possible edges" of the graph can be ordered lexicographically. For example, for a $4$-vertex graph, call the vertices $A, B, C, D$. The $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possible edges are
$$(AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD)$$
so a 4-vertex graph with $AC$ and $BC$ present would have index $2+10+1\cdot 2^1+1\cdot 2^3=22$.